# Under what conditions does Turkish Airlines provide a free hotel room to passengers on a long layover?

Tags: transit, layovers, turkish-airlines, ist

I have more than 12 hours transit time at Ataturk airport by Turkish airlines .. does company provide me a room or just stay at airport hall ,, and provide nothing?

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer is that they will provide a hotel if the shortest layover possible is more than 9 hours for Business Class passengers, or 12 hours for Economy passengers.

You can find more details of the program [on their website](https://www.turkishairlines.com/en-int/flights/hotel-service/index.html).

Comment: Note that you won't have a reservation. You go to "the hotel desk" and they set you up with a particular nearby hotel on the day. This is fine if you don't care where you sleep, you just want to sleep.